# Capistrano Trying to Deploy to Old IP Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy to our new production server.  Capistrano SSH into the server is working, yet the IP address listed below in the Terminal Output is an IP that we no longer use, and is nowhere in our Rails installation (we iterated all files).

How do I get Capistrano to stop trying to access this IP?  Where is it even coming from?  Is there a Capistrano cache that exists that could be holding this address?

**Terminal Output**

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as vadmin@15.1.153.247: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout

Caused by:
Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout

Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook => passenger:rvm:hook => passenger:test_which_passenger
```

**Capistrano Log Output**

```
  INFO START 2018-08-17 18:20:21 -0600 cap production doctor
  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 DEBUG [0244ff8e] Running /usr/bin/env which passenger as vadmin@15.153.1.30
 DEBUG [e9aebdc9] Running /usr/bin/env which passenger as vadmin@15.1.153.247
 DEBUG [0244ff8e] Command: ( export RVM_BIN_PATH="~/.rvm/bin" ; /usr/bin/env which passenger )
 DEBUG [e9aebdc9] Command: ( export RVM_BIN_PATH="~/.rvm/bin" ; /usr/bin/env which passenger )
```

**deploy.rb**

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.10.0"

set :application, "<omitted>"
set :repo_url, "ssh://<omitted>"

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, "/home/vadmin/<omitted>"

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 10

# set migration role to :app instead of :db
set :migration_role, :app

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure
```

**production.rb**

```
# server-based syntax
# ======================
# Defines a single server with a list of roles and multiple properties.
# You can define all roles on a single server, or split them:

server "15.153.1.30", user: "vadmin", roles: %w{app db web}
# server "example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w{app web}, other_property: :other_value
# server "db.example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w{db}

set :stage, :production

# role-based syntax
# ==================

# Defines a role with one or multiple servers. The primary server in each
# group is considered to be the first unless any hosts have the primary
# property set. Specify the username and a domain or IP for the server.
# Don't use `:all`, it's a meta role.

# role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}, my_property: :my_value
# role :web, %w{user1@primary.com user2@additional.com}, other_property: :other_value
# role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}



# Configuration
# =============
# You can set any configuration variable like in config/deploy.rb
# These variables are then only loaded and set in this stage.
# For available Capistrano configuration variables see the documentation page.
# http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/
# Feel free to add new variables to customise your setup.



# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
# You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
# limited set of options, consult the Net::SSH documentation.
# http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start
#
# Global options
# --------------
#  set :ssh_options, {
#    keys: %w(/home/rlisowski/.ssh/id_rsa),
#    forward_agent: false,
#    auth_methods: %w(password)
#  }
#
# The server-based syntax can be used to override options:
# ------------------------------------
# server "example.com",
#   user: "user_name",
#   roles: %w{web app},
#   ssh_options: {
#     user: "user_name", # overrides user setting above
#     keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
#     forward_agent: false,
#     auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
#     # password: "please use keys"
#   }
```

**gems**

```
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.10'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.3'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to look for this directory in your server `cached_repo` and delete it. This directory will get created in the next deployment.

In capistrano 3

You should remove this `$deploy_to/repo`